# Leaflet.TextPath: how to set zoom level from which text would be displayed

Tags: leaflet, labeling, zoom

I am using the [Leaflet.TextPath plugin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) for labeling polylines. It works fine into my Leaflet map, but I want to set the zoom level (scale-based visibility) from which labels would be displayed on the map.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> ...set the zoom level [...] from which [stuff] would be displayed on the map.

In Leaflet, you don't specify zoom levels for visibility and let Leaflet handle visibility (except for `L.TileLayer`s), but rather the other way around: depending on the zoom level, you make something (in)visible *by yourself*.

The usual way to do this is reacting to [`zoomend` events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-zoomend), e.g.:

```
var myMarker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map);
map.on('zoomend', function(ev){
    if (map.getZoom() < 12) {
        myMarker.addTo(map);
    } else { // when zoom >= 12
        myMarker.remove();
    }
});
```

If you're using Leaflet.TextPath then you probably don't want to `remove` and `addTo` any `L.Layer`s, but instead do something like

```
map.on('zoomend', function(ev){
    if (map.getZoom() < 12) {
        myPolyline.setText('something', {repeat: true});
    } else { // when zoom >= 12
        myPolyline.setText(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I changed "map.on" for "layer.on" and then that worked perfectly! Very grateful for this answer so detailed and clear. Just what I needed.

Comment: I'm impressed that even works - `L.Layer`s don't have a `zoomend` event. And as you're new here, let me remind you about [accepting answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I was wrong.. So you are right to be impressed because in fact is not working with layer.on. Not even with map.on. I will continue testing and as soon as I find a solution, I will notify it here. I take your reminder into consideration as well.